# SQL DateTime or string

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I have the following line in a TVF:

```
CASE WHEN MIN(ISNULL(EersteStart,GETDATE())) = GETDATE() 
then 'InOverleg' 
else  MIN(ISNULL(EersteStart,GETDATE())) end as EersteStartDatum
```

Except the fact that this seems kind of inefficiënt it still does not work, since
it generates the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I understand the error but how can I adjust the query to provide the functionality I want? (return string 'InOverleg' when the underlying query returns null for all EersteStartDatum fields of each row or show the MIN date when there are rows where EersteStartDatum is not NULL).

Comment: The only way is to return the date as a string

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_nam Im using SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is confusing?  `case` is an expression and needs to return one type.  SQL Server tends to convert to the more restrictive type.  In this `case`, the more restrictive time is a `datetime`.  `'InOverLeg'` does not convert.

You can convert the date to a string:

```
(CASE WHEN MIN(COALESCE(EersteStart, GETDATE())) = GETDATE() 
      THEN 'InOverleg' 
      ELSE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MIN(COALESCE(EersteStart, GETDATE())), 121) -- or whatever format you like
 END) as EersteStartDatum
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CAST(data_to_return AS varchar(my_desired_string_length))` for all your return data (then result and else result). Now you will have string returned in any case.